# Publish action with Facebook Open Graph

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm struggling, trying to implement Facebook Open Graph into my iOS application.
On the iOS code side, everything seems to work fine and I get the automatic confirmation msg that the Open Graph action has been published.

What is weird is that even if I edit the .html object on my server, the object published on facebook doesn't change. I always get the same object again and again. Does anybody know how is that possible?

This is how my object looks like:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# object: http://ogp.me/ns/object#">

    <title>Group App</title>
     <meta property="og:title" content="Test" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.groupapp.org/ita/attuale/icona.png" />
    <meta property="og:determiner" content="" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="172461289531661" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ruzzle/id504265646?mt=8" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="groupappitalia:object" />
```

Basically, I edit title, image and url; but nothing changes. Always get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ruzzle/id504265646?mt=8" />
```

That’s the actual address of your OG object. And so naturally this is also where Facebook retrieves the Open Graph info from, because that’s how the Open Graph works.

So you would have to change the attributes of that URL, and not your own page, to have these changes reflected on Facebook.